# why are my plants all dying? cucumbers, spaghetti squash and flowers?

Tags: diagnosis, plant-health, vegetables, flowers, watering

[image]

I just planted them last week, I watered them everyday until I saw that they were starting to die. some of the leaves are crispy, some of them are limp and soft. So I am not sure if I need to water them more or to water them less? I thought maybe they didn't get good oxygen from the soil. I bought the soil from the same nursey that I got the cukes from. did I need to mix the soil with mulch or something? I'm just trying to not kill everything. my flowers are also dying. the second I planted them they all started dying. [image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do the containers have drainage holes in them?

Answer (score 1):

In your first two pictures, it looks like you planted the seedlings too deep. The top of the compost that the seedling was growing in should be level with the soil surface when you transplant it. The pictures seem to show individual leaves poking out of the soil rather than a single stem of the plant, which looks like you "buried" the original plug of compost in the soil.

If that is what you did, the base of the plant stem will rot where it is buried in damp compost, which will kill the plant.

It's hard to see what went wrong with your flowers, from your photo looking straight down.